# Relative to tallest object option not working when frame shrinks

Tags: jasper-reports, border, frame, ireport

In the report, there are two frames that are in the same group and have selected Relative To Tallest Object option.

In the case, where one of the frames is extended because of the content overflow, the second frame extends relative to first frame.

In the case, when the first of the frames will shrink because of deleted text boxes from inside, that have Remove Line When Null option set, the height of the frame is reduced, despite the fact, that the Relative To Tallest Object option should ensure, that the size of the first frame is the same as the highest frame in group.

Problem occurs in JasperReports 4.7.1.

What can I do to get around this?

Image representing the problem:

[image: sample]

Content was erased due to privacy concerns.